# What is the best way to authenticated users with WCF by username and password

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

for the project i am making I need a WCF webservice that is secured using a username and password. The data of the authenticated user must be accesable in de webservice self, for logging purposes.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Microsofts article on this topic.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131.aspx)

More links:

1. [Custom User-Pass validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) to create you own user/pass storage
2. [Tutorial on wiring this all up](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/)

Comment: but how do you acces those values in the webservice

Comment: it depends on where do you want to store authentication data